# Postgresql query with custom type

Tags: postgresql, types

I have a custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE sbjct_with_count AS
(
  sbjct        dp.sbjct_v1,
  num_metrics  bigint
);
```

that uses this custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE sbjct_v1 AS
(
  sbjct_vrsn_id  integer,
  sbjct_id       integer,
  nm             text,
  dsc            text,
  db             text,
  tbl            text,
  pk             text,
  crtd_by        text,
  crtd_ts        timestamp without time zone,
  aprvd_by       text,
  aprvd_ts       timestamp without time zone,
  aprvd_stat     boolean,
  aprvd_del      boolean
);
```

And I have a query where I want to return a set of the first type (sbjct_with_count)

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT 
(s.sbjct_vrsn_id,
s.sbjct_id,
s.nm,
s.dsc,
s.db,
s.tbl,
s.pk,
s.crtd_by,
s.crtd_ts,
s.aprvd_by,
s.aprvd_ts,
s.aprvd_stat,
s.aprvd_del) as sbjct,
(SELECT COUNT(*) ... subquery)
FROM dp.sbjct s
... rest of query
```

How do I structure the return portion of the query to fit in with the type? I get the error `structure of query does not match function result type`

Answer (score 0):

You should use type casts:

```
SELECT CAST(
          ROW(
             CAST(ROW(..., ...) AS dp.sbjct_v1),
             ...
          ) AS sbjct_with_count
       )
FROM ...
```